# Being shorter of something

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I was having a chat with a friend earlier, at some point he said "you should have a score of 180, bit short of that aren't you? ;)", at which I responded with "I figure you're shorter :D".

Now, I guess this phrase can be interpreted in two ways:

- He is shorter than me **to** that score, hence he is closer to it;
- He is shorter **of** it than me, hence he has a lower score.

Which of the two interpretations is correct?

I get that the first interpretation may be correct when we are talking about a goal: "I am short of a goal" means that I am at some distance from achieving it, whereas "I am shorter than you of that same goal" might mean that I am at a closer distance from it compared to the other person (possibly?). I'm not really sure (that's why I am asking here in the end, we could not figure out who was "right").

Also, is relative superlative even allowed in this instance?

As my name suggests I am not a native speaker, so every bit of help is gonna be useful. Thanks!

Comment: I think saying "you are short of the target score" derives from the idiom "to fall short of something". Your friend might just as well have said "You should have a score of 180, but you have fallen short".

Comment: I am sure that that is the idiom his sentence derived from. We argued over it a bit and we were agreeing it was "to fall short of". I indeed answered him like that because I thought that using the relative superlative might have enforced the fact that he fell shorter of that score - i.e. he had scored lower than me - but we can't agree on what interpretation is grammatically correct. @WS2

Comment: More short (of target) (than I am) = grater gap (from target) (than I have).

Comment: The idiomatic expression is **further short of**, not 'more short of' or 'shorter of'. This is hard to show from Ngrams, as 'the shorter of ...' swamps relevant hits.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic form *to be short of [some target]* has effectively become a "fossilised" usage, which in the minds of natives speakers is divorced from the normal adjective ***short*** as an antonym of ***long***. And because of that, it doesn't have to follow the syntactic norms of the "ancestral" word.

So OP's **I figure you're shorter** justifies the **:D** just because it's "playing with language", since native speakers would say **I figure you're more short** if they were just using the idiom naturally, without thinking.

---

It might help to consider [***hotter-headed***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hotter-headed%22) as an alternative to [***more hot-headed***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22more%20hot-headed%22). If Google Books is to be believed, the latter is far more common than the former (which sounds "facetious" to me).

Comment: But by saying "I figure you're more short" what am I actually delivering? That I have a score lower than his or the other way around? That's what we can't really figure out :') anyway, thanks for your answer, it clarifies some things at least!

Answer (score 0):

> He is shorter than me to that score, hence he is closer to it;
>
> He is shorter of it than me, hence he has a lower score.

I would argue that the later interpretation is correct. The OP's friend initially provided the context of short. *i.e. where your score is relative to the benchmark*.

The use of shorter, refers back to that initial context and increases the degree of it.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, you cannot compare comparisons.

To say that A is short of B is already a comparison. You cannot say that C is even shorter, except in a joking and informal manner. Then of course it would mean that the shortage - i.e. the difference revealed by the comparison - is even greater.

To put it in other terms: ***[short of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/short)*** means ***less than***. *I am 30 points short of the minimum* means I have 30 points less than the required 180. To be *shorter*, your score would have to be more (*less than 180*) than my.

But we don't speak that way. To take the dictionary example, if *Adam died at sixty-one, four years short of his pensionable age*, you would reply that *Betty died even younger* -  not *Betty died even shorter.*

Comment: 'I was 10 marks short of getting an _A_, but Jill was further short.' See,
 for instance, [Informal Institutions and Democracy: Lessons from Latin America](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WT2OiQQg508C&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=%22fell+further+short%22+-%22a+further+short%22&source=bl&ots=qm1UKrFhiS&sig=BtYZerWwqPZiC8B7d5_cDIJHdV0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj15JCT8L_VAhVHAcAKHTAuD68Q6AEINjAE#v=onepage&q=%22fell%20further%20short%22%20-%22a%20further%20short%22&f=false).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is actually "fell further", not "further short".

Comment: 'Further' modifies 'short' in the example: '... fell further short of the mark ...'.

Comment: My answer is not wrong: you cannot say "A is shorter of B than C". The article you cite only goes to support this - otherwise why would they need to use the word "further" at all.

Comment: If 'A has fallen short of the pass/median ...  mark' can be considered a comparison, then so can 'C has fallen short of the pass/median ...  mark'. Thus 'C has fallen further short than A' compares comparisons.

Comment: No, it compares the **results** of those comparisons. You can certainly say that the difference between A and B is greater than the difference betwen A and C. You cannot say that A is "differenter" than C. Or "smallerer", to make a better analogy with the OP.